# Coded UI script to read from physical file location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am using Visual Studio 2013 (C#) for creating some automated test suit. I have created script for one of the test scenario. I want to use same script but in different test environment (e.g. UAT).

As I am new to coded ui I am using following process,

1. Record script in sys test environment using sys test link  and re run in same environment to verify
2. Now I want to run same script but using different link (different link to different environment e.g. UAT)

I want my script to read link from some xyz physical file location and whatever environment is specified in that file runs my script against that environment.
I did try same thing using data files (like .csv file within my project) but, in that case my system runs same script twice for both environment (sys n UAT) and I want to avoid running same scripts at same time for all environments

Hope my question is clear enough :-)

Thanks in advance to all!!

Comment: (1) Change the data file depending on which environment you want to test. Or (2) search for using environment variables in Coded UI tests, or search for passing parameters to Coded UI tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using app.config.

1. Double-click the properties 'folder' in your project
2. Go to the settings tab
3. If it is not set up yet, click the presented link to create a settings file
4. Create a variable (type string) and give it a name (e.g. TestUrl) and a default value (e.g. The test URL for the first environment)
5. Use 'Properties.Settings.Default.TestUrl' in your code
6. When you want to change environments, find the 'YourApplication.exe.config' file and edit the TestUrl key's value

Comment: Thanks AdrianHHH and DoronG. I tried data file, environment variable and app.config options. All worked well. Thanks to both of u.